# How to override standard mysql 5.7 container configuration

Tags: mysql, docker, my.cnf

I cannot replace the standard `/etc/my.cnf` file in a standard mysql 5.7 container.

I am running a mysql 5.7 container (standard Docker HUB image).
I want to replace the `etc/my.cnf` file to enable master-slave operations.
I want to achieve this by mounting the volume from the `docker-compose.yml` file.

The new `my.cnf` should be:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
user=mysql

# Replication and mirroring settings
server-id = 1
auto_increment_increment = 3
auto_increment_offset = 0
log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/log-bin
log_bin_index     = /var/log/mysql/log-bin.index
binlog_format     = row
expire_logs_days  = 10
log_slave_updates

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

In `docker-compose.yml` I have the following lines:

```
mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    container_name: rucio-mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-config/my-master.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
```

The paths are correct, but the container gets started and exits immediately.

Thanks in advance,

Slid

Comment: Does it print out anything when it exits?

Comment: It dies when the mysql configuration begins.
I switched to PostgreSQL which gives me better performance and configuration capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify files as volumes, it doesn't work so. Volumes are directories.

If your config is constant and is not expected to change between container executions, simply inherit your own container from `mysql/mysql-server:5.7` and `COPY` new config into it:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:5.7
COPY my.cnf /etc/
```

and use your new image in `docker-compose`.

If configuration is a matter of chages, better use volumes, but you will have to manually overwrite it upon container start. Something like this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    container_name: rucio-mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-config:/configs
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
    command: ["cp", "-f", "/configs/my-master.cnf", "/etc/my.cnf"]
```

Comment: "You cannot specify files as volumes". This is wrong you can specify files as volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the official [MySQL Docker repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) on dockerhub section "Configuration without a cnf file" it clearly mentions that you can provide configuration flags after the base image name which i find it rather easier to run rather than building a docker image.
My Example docker run command to optimise memory usage from default 480 mb to a mere 100 mb

docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=tooor -e MYSQL_USER=test -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=test -v /mysql:/var/lib/mysql --name mysqldb mysql --table_definition_cache=100 --performance_schema=0 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password